# Cakephp validating if my user checked at least one option

Tags: list, validation, checkbox, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem validating if my user checked at least one option from a list of checkboxes.

Here is what i tried:
My view looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('market_segment_targeted', array(
   'multiple' => 'checkbox',
   'label'=>array('text' => 'Market segment targeted', 'class'=>'w120'),
   'options' => array(
                'Home users' => 'Home users',
                'SOHO' => 'SOHO',
                'SMB' => 'SMB',
                'Enterprise' => 'Enterprise'
    ),
));
```

In my controller i have added this snippet of code:

```
    $validate_on_fly = array(
                         'market_segment_targeted' => array(
                        'notEmpty' => array(
    'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
                            'required' => true,
                            'message'  => 'Please select at least one!'
                        ))
                        )));    
    $this->Partner->validate = Set::merge(
                          $this->Partner->validate,
                          $validate_on_fly
                          );
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What's the problem? Does the model allow you to submit invalid data, or does it prevent submitting valid data?

Comment: I can submit this form without checking any option.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you didn't manually disable validation when saving your data or that you didn't modify your validation rules in your controller after saving the data? Put a debug($this->validate); in your beforeValidate() in Partner.php to check if you go through validation. And btw it's better to manage all validation in the model...

Comment: I know it is better to manage all the validation in the model, but this field is not contained in the model.. and i am not modifing my validation in any way :( it all looks good when i debug $this->validate, but for some reason i can submit the form without checking any option.

Comment: can you show all the function where you make your validation on the fly ? and maybe also your Partner Model's $validate or beforeValidate() if either one is defined ?

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP you can use Model Validation for checkboxes. Here is a quick example.

Your **Form** can look like:

```
$this->Form->create('User');
$this->Form->input('User.agree', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'hiddenField'=>false, 'value'=>'0'));
$this->Form->submit('Save'):
$this->Form->end();
```

Then in your **Model** under public $validate, use:

```
'agree'=>array(
  'Not empty'=>array(
    'rule'=>array('comparison', '!=', 0),
    'required'=>true,
    'message'=>'You must agree to the ToS'
    )
  )
```